# Required field missing when importing dates from Mysql to Solr

Tags: mysql, datetime, solr

I'm having problems getting solr and mysql dates to play nice. If I comment out the `sent` field from the schema everything works fine. However, as soon as I add back in the date field I get this error for every document.

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: [doc=116] missing required field: sent
```

Here's how I have solr configured. I've ched to make sure that there are no empty/null dates and there are not. I've also tried dateTimeFormat=`yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss` and no dateTimeFormat being set. I've also tried both date and tdate for the type of sent in the schema.

dataconfig.xml

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hoplite" user="root" password="root"/>
    <document>
        <entity name="document" query="select * from document">
            <field column="ID" name="id" />
            <field column="RAW_TEXT" name="raw_text" />    
            <entity name="email" query="select * from email where document_id='${document.id}'">                
                <field column="TIME_SENT" name="sent" dateTimeFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'"/> 
                <field column="BODY" name="body" />
            </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

schema.xml

```
   <field name="id" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
   <field name="raw_text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" required="true" multiValued="true"/>   

   <field name="sent" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> <!-- Import succeeds if I comment this line out -->
   <field name="body" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently for dates the field name has to be the same as the column name. So changing the files to the below fixed the problem. Note that time_sent is now both the column and field name.

data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hoplite" user="root" password="root"/>
    <document>
        <entity name="document" query="select * from document">
            <field column="ID" name="id" />
            <field column="RAW_TEXT" name="raw_text" />

            <entity name="email" query="select * from email where document_id='${document.id}'">                
                <field column="TIME_SENT" name="time_sent" dateTimeFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'"/>
                <field column="BODY" name="body" />
            </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

schema.xml

```
   <field name="id" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
   <field name="raw_text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" required="true" multiValued="true"/>   

   <field name="time_sent" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> <!-- Import succeeds if I comment this line out -->
   <field name="body" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
```